# How can I efficiently find conditional duplicates in a data table?

Tags: r, datatable

I have a data frame that is about 6 million lines and I am running into computational limits. The data I have are unnested ngrams produced by many states across 8 years. I want the proportion of ngrams that each state has copied from other states in the previous year. To do this, I am labeling each line and then aggregating at the end. This takes forever! My code is below, is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
tidy2 <- data.table(District = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
                    year = c(2015,2016,2017,2015,2016,2017,2015,2016,2017),
                    ngram = c('X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Y', 'W', 'Q', 'W', 'X', 'X'),
                    want_col = c(F, T, F, F, T, F, F, T, F))


dists <- unique(tidy2$District)
year <- unique(tidy2$year)
for(i in year) {

  for(j in dists) {
    
    tidy2[year == i & District == j & ngram %in% tidy2[year == i-1 & District != j, ngram], followed := 1]

    tidy2[year == i &  District == j & ngram %in% tidy2[year == i+1 & District != j, ngram], lead := 1]
    
    print(j)
  }
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: Include the output that you expect from the data above. Also since you are using `data.table` try to not use loops. Try using vectorized functions

Comment: If the ngrams don't appear too often, it might be more efficient to do a join by ngram and year (offset by 1), and then filter. I'm not sure the data.table syntax, but in dplyr it could be `tidy2 %>% left_join(tidy2 %>% mutate(year_shift = year + 1), by = c("ngram", "year" = "year_shift")) %>% filter(District.x != District.y, !is.na(District.y))`. That outputs the three `want_col = TRUE` rows.

Comment: I have some doubts on what you goal is after your code, nevertheless i think you can calculate proportions in this way: `tidy2[, prop := sum(ngram %in% tidy2[District==D & year==Y-1, ngram]) / .N,  by = .(D=District, Y=year)]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand about the proportion you mentioned. But, for the labeling, you can use this.

1. Group the data by `ngram`.
2. For each `ngram` group, check whether it has more than one member.
3. if yes, assign smallest `year` as `lead` and others as `followed`

This is the code:

```
    library(dplyr)
    tidy2 %>% 
       group_by(ngram) %>% 
       mutate(followed = ifelse(year != min(year) & n() > 1,1,NA), lead = ifelse(year == min(year) & n() > 1,1,NA)) %>% 
       ungroup()
```